# Network Analyst directions window options

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, routing, network-analyst

I have created a vehicle route problem with multiple route zones with one depot in each zone. Each zone has a pickup route that delivers to the depot in the zone. Some addresses have special instructions for where to pickup the item from their property as well as a phone number.

My question is whether or not there is a way to make any special instructions or any other information like a phone number appear in the directions window to be printed out for the driver?

I'm using Network Analyst in ArcGIS 9.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

When this question was asked at ArcGIS 9.3.1 I suspect your options were few which may explain no one having answered.

With ArcPy's Network Analyst module becoming available at ArcGIS 10.1 (I think) I recommend you take a look at **[arcpy.na.Directions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//004800000007000000)** to see if this may now be possible.